# Is $\{e^{-kn}\sin(kn^2\pi)\}_{n=1}^{n=\infty}$ =$\{0\}_{n=1}^{\infty}?$

Tags: real-analysis

Given a family of sequences $$\{e^{-kn}\sin(kn^2\pi)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$$

Explicitly,
$$\{e^{-kn}\sin(kn^2\pi)\}_{n=1}^{n=\infty}$$ = $$\{(e^{-n}\sin(n^2\pi))_{n=1}^\infty,(e^{-2n}\sin(2n^2\pi))_{n=1}^\infty,(e^{-3n}\sin(3n^2\pi))_{n=1}^\infty,....\} $$

since $\sin(m\pi)=0$ for all integer $m$, so$$\{e^{-kn}\sin(kn^2\pi)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$$=$$\{0\}_{n=1}^{\infty}?$$

Comment: can you explain it

Comment: Is $k$ also an integer?

Comment: Yes, if $k$ is an integer, then $e^{-kn}\sin(kn^2\pi)$ is just a complicated way to write $0$. If $k$ is not integer, not at all: only some terms *may* equal $0$.

Comment: And $\{\cdot\}_{n=1}^{n=\infty}$ means you are talking about a sequence?

Comment: Sorry everyone, I didn't make it clear. I just edited it and hope everyone could understand it. Your opinions definitely help me make my question clear, please leave your comment here if I still make you confused, since I just learned family of sequence a few days ago. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Hetebrij it should be $\{e^{-kn}\sin(kn^2\pi)\}$